# Processing files from shell script to argument inside python

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am manually running file with command line

```
python script.py input_files/input.txt text_out/output.json
```

while inside `script.py`
there is

```
input_path = sys.argv[1]
out_path = sys.argv[2]
```

now I have shell script and I want to make it for all files in one go.
I am facing issue.

My shell script is like below
there are two folders 1) `input_files` and 2) `text_out`

```
for i in input_files/*.txt;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  python script.py -i "$i" text_out/"${name}.json"
done
```

but when I execude .sh as stated above, it is throwing error as sys.argv is not picking properly.

```
out_path = sys.argv[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you can guide what to change in `.py` or in shell `.sh` script would be kind.

Comment: You forgot to pass the input file as the first argument to `script.py`.

Comment: I tried python script.py $i text_out/"${name}.json" but it didn't work

Comment: Run your shell script with `-x` to see what arguments are actually getting passed to python.

Comment: Thank you all and specially @kojiro and mportes. I finally resolved it. Below is my own answer and correction ! if you can accept it.

Comment: @ML85 only you can accept the answer to your own question. But please do take a look at my answer on argparse. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in input_files/*.txt;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"
  python script.py "$i" text_out/"${name}.json"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why you're getting a ListIndexOutOfRange, but it doesn't really matter, since you're also passing `-i` after script.py, so out_path cannot be what you expect.

```
$ cat script.py 
import sys; print(len(sys.argv)); print(sys.argv); print({i:v for i, v in enumerate(sys.argv)})

$ (set -x; i=input_files/foo.txt; name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`; python script.py -i "$i" text_out/"${name}.json")
+ i=input_files/foo.txt
++ echo input_files/foo.txt
++ cut -d. -f1
+ name=input_files/foo
+ python script.py -i input_files/foo.txt text_out/input_files/foo.json
4
['script.py', '-i', 'input_files/foo.txt', 'text_out/input_files/foo.json']
{0: 'script.py', 1: '-i', 2: 'input_files/foo.txt', 3: 'text_out/input_files/foo.json'}
```

I recommend using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) whenever you need to deal with cli arguments in Python. It will give better feedback and reduce the ambiguity of looking directly at indices.

```
$ cat script2.py 
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
parser.add_argument('output_file', type=argparse.FileType('w'))
print(parser.parse_args())

$ (set -x; i=input_files/foo.txt; name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`; python script2.py -i "$i" text_out/"${name}.json")
+ i=input_files/foo.txt
++ echo input_files/foo.txt
++ cut -d. -f1
+ name=input_files/foo
+ python script2.py -i input_files/foo.txt text_out/input_files/foo.json
Namespace(input_file=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='input_files/foo.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, output_file=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text_out/input_files/foo.json' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the `IndexError: list index out of range` error because you try to access the list at index 2 for `out_path` (in your Python script).

But in your shell script you're just passing one argument in the Python script (at this line: `python script.py text_out/"${name}.json"`).

Your first example (`python script.py input_files/input.txt text_out/output.json`) works ofc, because you're just passing two arguments into the Python script. That's why you can access `sys.argv` easily at index **1** and **2**.

You should check the length of `len(sys.argv)` to know how many arguments are passed into the Python script.

#### Example Shell Script

Your shell script should look something like this to get rid if the `IndexError`:

```sh
for i in input_files/*.txt;
  do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
  echo "$name"1

  # Pass two args into your Python script
  python script.py input.txt output.txt
done
```

Comment: of course it is working with (python script.py input_files/input.txt text_out/output.json)